# How to convert a very large decimal number to a string?

Tags: javascript, string, numbers, decimal

I want to convert the decimal number `123.456e+304` to the string `"123.456e+304"` (the position of the decimal point `.` should not be changed).

Here is what I've tried, but all of them return the same result: `1.23456e+306` (the position of the decimal point has been changed, and it has also replaced `304` with `306`).

```js
var e = 123.456e+304;

console.log(e.toString());
console.log((e).toString());
console.log(e .toString());
console.log(e.toFixed());
console.log(String(e));
console.log((new String(e)).toString());
console.log(`${e}`);
console.log('' + e);
console.log(e + '');
console.log(''.split.call(e, '').join(''));
```

Is there any way to convert it to the expect string `"123.456e+304"`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible, because once you assigned:

```
var e = 123.456e+304;
```

and is processed by the JavaScript interpreter, `e` is just a number internally represented by IEEE 754 a number equivalent to 1.23456e+306 and it has "no memory" where your decimal point was.  So no matter what you do, you can't know where the decimal point was and let you move it to where you want it to be in a string.

In order "to have the knowledge" of where the decimal point was, you need to have a string to begin with, but that's also the result that you want.

Comment: It should be noted that the IEEE 754 format is a binary, not a decimal, floating-point format; it doesn't even have a notion of a _decimal point_.  If it were a _decimal_ floating-point format (e.g.,  IEEE 854r's `decimal64` or `decimal128`), then it might be able to represent some decimal values such as `123.456e+304` without loss.

Comment: My first idea is: getting the last character of the output string `6`, then substracting it with the number of the decimal point movement and updating a new string but still getting stuck with the decimal point. Since you've noted that `You can't know where the decimal point was`, so I think my idea cannot be done. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Tân yes... unless you know the integer part is always 3 digits, or decimal part is always 3 digits, etc... in which case you can use something like `123.456.toString().match(/(\d)/g)` to do some processing